# Joining on 2 columns including NULL values in those columns

Tags: sql, database, join

I am looking to create a sub-query that matches against a grouping set table I have created, the grouping sets are the same in both tables.  I have run them and they match for the first 2 columns (where the join will occur).  The grouping sets essentially create a Null value in the first column, Line of Business with 3 options) (to sum all of the output) and then 4 NULLs in the second column to sub-total each.  Whenever I try join the sub-query, the NULL rows show a NULL output.

```sql
SELECT 
c.LINE_OF_BUSINESS_ENG
,CLAIM_TYPE_GROUP
,COUNT(SUB_CLAIM_ID) SUB_CLAIMS
,SAVINGS
FROM CLAIMS c

left join( 
SELECT
LINE_OF_BUSINESS_ENG
,CLAIM_TYPE_GROUP_MAPPED
,SUM(RR_SAVINGS_AMOUNT) SAVINGS
FROM CLAIMS_RR rr
left join CLAIMS c on rr.SUB_CLAIM_ID=c.SUB_CLAIM_ID
WHERE CLAIM_TYPE_GROUP_MAPPED is not NULL
and LINE_OF_BUSINESS_ENG is not null
GROUP BY
GROUPING SETS(
(LINE_OF_BUSINESS_ENG,CLAIM_TYPE_GROUP_MAPPED)
,(LINE_OF_BUSINESS_ENG)
,())) RR on RR.LINE_OF_BUSINESS_ENG=c.LINE_OF_BUSINESS_ENG
AND (RR.CLAIM_TYPE_GROUP_MAPPED = c.CLAIM_TYPE_GROUP OR (RR.CLAIM_TYPE_GROUP_MAPPED IS NULL AND c.CLAIM_TYPE_GROUP IS NULL))

WHERE CLAIM_TYPE_GROUP is not NULL
GROUP BY
GROUPING SETS(
(c.LINE_OF_BUSINESS_ENG,CLAIM_TYPE_GROUP,SAVINGS)
,(c.LINE_OF_BUSINESS_ENG)
,())
```

This is my query, but I know the join isn't correct.  How do I go about joining this correctly??  I have spent days trying to work this out.

One table is new claims:

| LOB | CLAIM_TYPE | CLAIM_NUMBER |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Liability | EL | CLAIM-01 |
| Liability | PL - PD | CLAIM-02 |
| Liability | PL - PI | CLAIM-03 |
| Liability | PL - PI | CLAIM-04 |
| Motor | Motor OD | CLAIM-05 |
| Motor | Motor PI | CLAIM-06 |
| Motor | Motor TPPD | CLAIM-07 |
| Motor | Windscreen | CLAIM-08 |
| Motor | Motor TPPD | CLAIM-09 |
| Property | PD/BI | CLAIM-10 |
| Property | PD/BI | CLAIM-11 |

One is savings made on claims:

| LOB | CLAIM_TYPE | RR_SAVING_AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Liability | EL | 10 |
| Liability | PL - PD | 15 |
| Liability | PL - PI | 10 |
| Liability | PL - PI | 50 |
| Motor | Motor OD | 80 |
| Motor | Motor PI | 30 |
| Motor | Motor TPPD | 12 |
| Motor | Windscreen | 50 |
| Motor | Motor TPPD | 75 |
| Property | PD/BI | 100 |
| Property | PD/BI | 250 |

And result should look like:

| LOB | CLAIM_TYPE | COUNT_CLAIM_NUMBER | SUM_RR_SAVINGS_AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NULL | NULL | 11 | 682 |
| Liability | NULL | 4 | 85 |
| Liability | EL | 1 | 10 |
| Liability | PL - PD | 1 | 15 |
| Liability | PL - PI | 2 | 60 |
| Motor | NULL | 5 | 247 |
| Motor | Motor OD | 1 | 80 |
| Motor | Motor PI | 1 | 30 |
| Motor | Motor TPPD | 2 | 87 |
| Motor | Windscreen | 1 | 50 |
| Property | NULL | 2 | 350 |
| Property | PD/BI | 2 | 350 |

Comment: Please update your question with example data for your source tables and the result you want to achieve based on that data - all as editable text

Comment: Please re-open your question and tag it with the DBMS you are using and I may be able to provide you with an answer

Answer (score 0):

You haven't tagged your question with the DBMS you are using but assuming it supports all of this syntax, the following should give you what you want:

```
WITH CLAIM_COUNT AS (
        SELECT
            C.LOB,
            C.CLAIM_TYPE,
            COUNT(DISTINCT C.CLAIM_NUMBER) COUNT_CLAIM_NUMBER
        FROM
            CLAIMS C
        GROUP BY
            C.LOB,
            C.CLAIM_TYPE
    ),
    SAVING_SUM AS (
        SELECT
            LOB,
            CLAIM_TYPE,
            SUM(RR_SAVING_AMOUNT) RR_SAVING_AMOUNT
        FROM
            SAVINGS
        GROUP BY
            LOB,
            CLAIM_TYPE
    )
SELECT
    C.LOB,
    C.CLAIM_TYPE,
    SUM(COUNT_CLAIM_NUMBER) COUNT_CLAIM_NUMBER,
    SUM(S.RR_SAVING_AMOUNT)
FROM
    CLAIM_COUNT C
    INNER JOIN SAVING_SUM S ON C.LOB = S.LOB
    AND C.CLAIM_TYPE = S.CLAIM_TYPE
GROUP BY
    ROLLUP (C.LOB, C.CLAIM_TYPE)
ORDER BY
    C.LOB NULLS FIRST,
    C.CLAIM_TYPE NULLS FIRST;
```